# Data binding in VueJS to build a URL

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, vue.js, vuejs2

Having my first go with VueJS which is great. Just got a couple of issues with data binding.

- I need the customer to enter an image, so no image should show until a url is entered in the input field. At the moment, it shows a broken image whilst waiting for an image from the customer.
- I need to build a URL with a static URL (amazon.com) with the binded image appended to the url. I have tried v-bind:href with no joy

  ```
  <div class="main" id="vue-instance">
  <!-- this will be the DOM element we will mount our VueJs instance to -->
  Enter an image url:
  <input type="text" v-model="myimage">

  <img class="insert" style="max-height:300px" v-bind:src="myimage">
  <a href="https://amazon.com" target="_blank">Link to the image</a>
  </div>
  ```

Here is the code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edkmsyru/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set myimage='' or null initially. Then You can use v-if statement to only show the image and image link if there is some value in myimage

```
<div v-if="myimage">
    <img class="insert" style="max-height:300px" v-bind:src="myimage">
    <a v-bind:href="'https://amazon.com/' + myimage" target="_blank">Link to the image</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-bind:href and then normal javascript inside the property like below

```
<a v-bind:href="'https://amazon.com/' + myimage" target="_blank">Link to the image</a>
```

note the additional `''` in the `v-bind` property

As for not displaying the image until after a url is entered, you can use a simple `v-show`

```
<img class="insert" style="max-height:300px" v-show="myimage != null" v-bind:src="myimage">
```

This will hide the image when `myimage` is null

Comment: Just having an issue with getting the image to shown when a url is entered. Seems to set it to display:none, should it be the other way round ie. != https://jsfiddle.net/edkmsyru/

Comment: Looks like the null part isn't needed,just do ```v-show="myimage"```

Comment: My mistake, you are correct, it should indeed be != null. The null part could be required. For example if you type '0' I think it will still evaluate to false even though you have typed something.